# How to stop an UIView animation in swift

Tags: swift, animation, uiview

I'm working with Swift language. I wrote an animation for a timer that lasts for 30 seconds and is full. Now I want to stop this animation, but I do not know how! I want to be able to start again from the beginning. Animation.
Thanks if you have a solution or a method that helps me

Comment: Depending on your needs you could consider using UIViewPropertyAnimator. Read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
self.myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways:

- Somewhere store variable for total time. And in every timer repeat increase this value. When total time reaches 30 seconds, remove animation
- When you start animation, set action which gets executed after specific time

First possible way:

```
var time: Double = 0

@objc func timerChangedValue() {
    time += 1
    if time == 30 {
        view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Second possible way:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: layoutIfNeeded is useless